# How to format y-axis to show percentage with Python Jupyter Notebook lmplot?

Tags: python

I'm a new python user and I need help in formatting the plot's y-axis.

I need to format the y-axis to show percentage [See Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNb6v.png). Ex: .015 to 1.5%

```
    r = 
    sns.lmplot('DefectWeek','Rate',col='Reason',data=df,sharey=True, 
    ci=95, aspect=.7)
    r = (r.fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.01))
```